# C# Excel cell content partially strikeout

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, excel-interop

Does anyone have any idea in detecting the data of a particular cells in
Excel is partially strikeout?

I have tried :

```
cell.IsStrikeThrough = System.Convert.ToBoolean(rowFound.Font.Strikethrough);
```

the cell is simply an struct object, and the rowFound is Excel.Range object.

This line of code works fine if the content in the rowFound is fully
strikeout or not strikeout. But when it comes to a cell's data which is
partially strikeout, it will return an System.DBNull.

Appreciate if anyone can provide an idea or example to check if the content
in a cell is partially strikeout, and how to determine the characters of the
cell where it starts to strikeout.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Late response but in case it helps anyone else...

I think this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb223824%28v%3doffice.12%29 indicates that the Font object will be System.DBNull whenever the cell contains a mix of font properties.

So you can test for System.DBNull with Convert.IsDBNull() and in such circumstances enter a method where you test the individual .Characters property of the cell to decide what you want to do - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb213514%28v%3doffice.12%29.

Hope that helps.